# Assert when ObjectDoesNotExitst is raise

Tags: python, django

I have this function which raises the `ObjectDoesNotExist`

```
def is_user_login(self,id):
    try:
        u = m.CustomUser.objects.get(id=id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        raise e
```

Now I am writing the test script.

```
    try:
        CommonFunc.is_user_login(4)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        self.assertEqual(ObjectDoesNotExist,e)
```

It doesn't work.

It shows error like this below ,

```
AssertionError: <class 'django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist'> != DoesNotExist('CustomUser matching query does not exist.')
```

How can I assert for `ObjectDoesNotEqual`?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done with an [**`.assertRaises(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) context processor:

```
with self.assertRaises(ObjectDoesNotExist):
    CommonFunc.is_user_login(4)
```

However re-raising the exception however does not seem to make much sense, why not:

```
def is_user_login(self, id):
    # no try
    u = m.CustomUser.objects.get(id=id)
```